# Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+e^x)}{x} = 1$

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

Show that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1 + e^x)}{x} = 1$$
How do I prove this? Or how do we get this result? Here $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Its $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form .. we can use L'Hospital's rule ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Taylor series? nope can't use that either

Comment: Is $\log(x)=\ln(x)$ in your question?

Comment: Yes it is the natural log

Comment: Almost duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196070/find-lim-x-to-infty-lnx1-lnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** How about using $\displaystyle e^x < 1+e^x < 2e^x$, for $x > 0$, taking $\log$ and apply the Squeeze Theorem to conclude the required limit is $1$. (which is essentially same as the other hints).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on this one

Comment: @WalterMitty $\log x$ is an increasing function on $(0,\infty)$, so using log on the aforementioned inequality gives us $\displaystyle \log e^x < \log 1+e^x < \log 2 + \log e^x$, now divide the expression with x, see that the upper and lower bounds both approach the limit $1$ as $x \to \infty$, thus squeeze theorem implies $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1 + e^x)}{x} = 1$

Comment: Okay I understand. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For $x\to\infty$

$$\log(1+e^x)\sim\log(e^x)=x$$

Therefore, the limit can be easily simplified

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+e^x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that
$$\log(1 + e^x) = \log[e^x (1 + e^{-x})]$$

> $$\cdots= \log e^x + \log(1 + e^{-x}) = x + \log(1 + e^{-x}).$$

Comment: Thanks, @PetiteEtincelle, and you're welcome, Mitty, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\log(1+e^x) = \log(e^x) + (\log(1+e^x) - \log(e^x))=x + \log\left(\frac{1+e^x}{e^x}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x \to +\infty$, By using L'Hospital's rule:

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}=1-\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^x}=1$$

If $x\to -\infty$, It equals 0

So I'm sorry to tell you that this limit does not exist!

Comment: OP says he can't use L'Hospital's rules.

Comment: Wo, he doesn't say in OP but in comments, if you don't remind, I really don't see it!

Answer (score 0):

You may write, as $x$ tends to $+\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log (1+e^x)}{x}&=\frac{\log\left(e^x (1+e^{-x})\right)}{x}\\\\
&=\frac{x+\log(1+e^{-x})}{x}\\\\
&=1+\frac{\log(1+e^{-x})}{x}\\\\
&=1+\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{e^{-2x}}{x}\right)\\\\
\end{align}
$$
 where we have used $$\log(1+u) =u+\mathcal{O}(u^2)$$ for $u$ near $0$.

Comment: While this answer is good, it is not elementary, since it uses Taylor expansions of the logarithm function. OP said he cannot use L'Hospital or Taylor.