# Use L'Hospital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x \cdot \arctan(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to evaluate 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x \cdot \arctan(x)}$$

Using L'Hospital, I get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}}{\arctan(x)+\frac{x}{1+x^2}}$$

Now I could use L'Hospital again, but it seems like it's not going to give me a result where I can conveniently take the limit.

Any hints?

Comment: You are done already at the first step. The second limit is finite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+e^x)}{x} = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005495/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-frac-log1exx-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said elsewhere, your second limit is not as difficult as you think (it is $\frac{1}{\frac\pi2+0}$).

To check your work, an intuitive approach is possible for the first limit: for large $x$, $e^x$ is huge in front of $1$, so that $\log(e^x+1)$ is virtually $x$.

Now after simplification all that remains is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\arctan(x)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Without L'Hospital

$$\frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x \cdot \arctan(x)}=\frac{1}{ \arctan(x)}\frac{\ln(1+\frac1{e^x})+\ln (e^x)}{x}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{ \arctan(x)}\left(\frac{\ln(1+\frac1{e^x})}{x}+1\right)\to \frac 2 \pi\cdot1=\frac 2 \pi$$

Answer (score 2):

As $x \to \infty$ $\arctan x \to \pi/2$. So it is enough to find the limit of $\frac {ln (1+e^{x})} x$. You can apply L'Hopital's rule for this.  The answer is $\frac 2 {\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac{e^x}{1 + e^x}\to 1$, $\arctan(x)\to \frac\pi2$ and $\frac{x}{x^2 + 1}\to 0$. So the second limit is rather easy to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1+\mathrm e^x\sim_{+\infty}\mathrm e^x$, so $\;\ln(1+\mathrm e^x)\sim_{+\infty}\ln(\mathrm e^x)=x$. On the other hand, $\;\arctan x\sim_{+\infty}\frac\pi2$, so that
$$ \frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{x \cdot \arctan(x)}\sim_{+\infty}\frac x{x\,\frac\pi 2}=\frac2\pi.$$